# Tap through transparent part of UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uikit, touch

I have a scroll view with transparent background that covers most of the screen. It also covers some buttons that still need to be tap-able. How can I make sure that the scroll view doesn't respond to touches in regions where the subview image is transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to override `hitTest:withEvent:` in your scroll view.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The solution for me was overriding
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;